# What is the router feature called that announces your IP address to DynDNS or similar?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address, dynamic-ip

I can't remember what it was called but there was a way for your router to announce to an online service what its IP address was, so that you only had to remember a name assigned to you by the online service rather than the dynamic IP address that your ISP assigned to you.

What is this feature called?

Comment: +1 for both jer.salamon and thepurplepixel both answers were what I was looking for. Best answer to thepurplepixel for answering first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called Dynamic DNS, or DDNS. Some popular DDNS providers are [DynDNS](http://dyndns.com) and [No-IP](http://no-ip.com). Many router firmwares like [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com) have DDNS support built in.

Answer (score 3):

[dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com) most routers support updating it with your dynamic router info and you can set up a hostname with them for free.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Dynamic DNS" .. an agent on the router (or on a PC behind the router) will update the Dynamic DNS service on a regular basis.

Some consumer routers have dynamic DNS agents built into them. Or, many consumer routers can have the built-in software replaced with an open-source broadband router OS such as [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato).

[Justin Scott](https://serverfault.com/users/671/justin-scott), a regular on Server Fault, runs DtDNS, a dynamic DNS hosting service.